# How eager Blender is about the GPU?

Tags: interface, gpu

Just got my Fedora upgraded to version 27 and running there Blender 2.79. While using it I have faced a bit bad UI (it is not following what I'm selecting) or the who screen gets messy. See the exaple:
[image]

When I move the mouse, the screen gets updated correctly and suddenly it gets back to this. I started Blender with smaller screen, but then extended to full screen.

I do have a pretty old GPU: Radeon HD 6970 so I wonder could that be the reason for the behavior like this? So far, I haven't seen any other GPU related issues.

--
Pepi

Comment: The drivers for the card are not working correctly. Re-install them, upgrade them, or get an exorcist to chase the demons out of your computer.